# How to control 3D CSS cube with controls

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to control the cube with arrows (up, down, left, right arrow controls). The problem i'm having is nothing is going on when i press the arrows i'm not sure if it's a Javascript issue or CSS keyframe issue. Another problem i'm having is that once the cube rotates i cant get it to rotate in the same direction when the key is pressed again or keep it in state. No JQuery please. This is what i have tried:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    let rotate = document.querySelectorAll('.rotate');
    let container = document.querySelector('.container');

function rotLeft (key) {
    element.animate(rotateLeft);
}

function rotRight (key) {
    element.animate(rotateRight);
}

function rotUp (key) {
    element.animate(rotateUp);
}

function rotDown (key) {
    element.animate(rotateDown);
}

if (key.keyCode == "37"){
    rotLeft();
}
else if (key.keyCode == "39"){
    rotRight();
}
else if (key.keyCode == "38"){
    rotUp();
        }
else if (key.keyCode == "40"){
    rotDown();
}

});
```

```css
.cube {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: translateZ(-100px);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.cube.show-front  { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(   0deg); }
.cube.show-right  { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY( 90deg); }
.cube.show-back   { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(-180deg); }
.cube.show-left   { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(  -90deg); }
.cube.show-top    { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX( -90deg); }
.cube.show-bottom { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(  90deg); }

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.side,
.container {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
}

.side {
  position: absolute;
  height: 160px;
  width: 160px;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.back {
  transform: translateZ(-80px);
  background-color: gold;
}

.left {
  transform: translateX(-80px) rotateY(90deg);
  background-color: gold;
}

.right {
  transform: translateX(80px) rotateY(90deg);
  background-color: gold;
}

.top {
  transform: translateY(-80px) rotateX(90deg);
  background-color: gold;
}

.bottom {
  transform: translateY(80px) rotateX(90deg);
  background-color: gold;
}

.front {
  transform: translateZ(80px);
  background-color: gold;
}

.container {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}



.animate {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  color: wheat;
  display: flex;
}

.rotate {
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: black;
}

.rotateCube {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: rotateLeft;
}

@keyframes rotateLeft {
  0% {
    transform: rotate3d(0); 
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,90deg); 
  }
}

@keyframes rotateRight {
  0% {
    transform: rotate3d(0); 
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate3d(0,-1,0,-90deg); 
  }
}

@keyframes rotateUp {
  0% {
    transform: rotate3d(0); 
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate3d(1,0,0,90deg); 
  }
}

@keyframes rotateDown {
  0% {
    transform: rotate3d(0); 
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate3d(0,-1,0,-90deg); 
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="rotateCube" class="cube">
    <div class="back side">back</div>
    <div class="left side">left</div>
    <div class="right side">r</div>
    <div class="top side">t</div>
    <div class="bottom side">b</div>
    <div class="front side">Front</div>

  </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to use the 'keyup' event.

Answer (score 1):

In order to catch an arrow key event you need to use:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  console.log("keyCode is: " + e.keyCode);
};
```

I've added the code to the functions in order to rotate the cube (I've just added the class already defined in the css with js). This is the result:

```js
let cube = document.getElementById("rotateCube");

function rotLeft() {
  resetCube()
  cube.className += " " + "show-left";
}

function rotRight() {
  resetCube()
  cube.className += " " + "show-right";
}

function rotUp() {
  resetCube()
  cube.className += " " + "show-top";
}

function rotDown() {
  resetCube()
  cube.className += " " + "show-bottom";
}

function resetCube() {
  cube.className = "cube";
}


document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.keyCode == "37") {
    rotLeft();
  } else if (e.keyCode == "39") {
    rotRight();
  } else if (e.keyCode == "38") {
    rotUp();
  } else if (e.keyCode == "40") {
    rotDown();
  }
};
```

```css
.cube {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: translateZ(-100px);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.cube.show-front  { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(   0deg); }
.cube.show-right  { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY( 90deg); }
.cube.show-back   { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(-180deg); }
.cube.show-left   { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(  -90deg); }
.cube.show-top    { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX( -90deg); }
.cube.show-bottom { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(  90deg); }

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.side,
.container {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
}

.side {
  position: absolute;
  height: 160px;
  width: 160px;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.back {
  transform: translateZ(-80px);
  background-color: gold;
}

.left {
  transform: translateX(-80px) rotateY(90deg);
  background-color: gold;
}

.right {
  transform: translateX(80px) rotateY(90deg);
  background-color: gold;
}

.top {
  transform: translateY(-80px) rotateX(90deg);
  background-color: gold;
}

.bottom {
  transform: translateY(80px) rotateX(90deg);
  background-color: gold;
}

.front {
  transform: translateZ(80px);
  background-color: gold;
}

.container {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}



.animate {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  color: wheat;
  display: flex;
}

.rotate {
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: black;
}

.rotateCube {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: rotateLeft;
}

@keyframes rotateLeft {
  0% {
    transform: rotate3d(0); 
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,90deg); 
  }
}

@keyframes rotateRight {
  0% {
    transform: rotate3d(0); 
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate3d(0,-1,0,-90deg); 
  }
}

@keyframes rotateUp {
  0% {
    transform: rotate3d(0); 
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate3d(1,0,0,90deg); 
  }
}

@keyframes rotateDown {
  0% {
    transform: rotate3d(0); 
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate3d(0,-1,0,-90deg); 
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="rotateCube" class="cube">
    <div class="back side">back</div>
    <div class="left side">left</div>
    <div class="right side">r</div>
    <div class="top side">t</div>
    <div class="bottom side">b</div>
    <div class="front side">Front</div>

  </div>
```

Comment: This is the secondary issue i had. It's not about showing each side but to get it to rotate a certain direction multiple times. I.e to click left arrow and it rotates left, click the left arrow again and it rotates left again

Comment: @BubblegumPrincess can't code the whole logic for you, edit this one or open another question with what you've tried so far so we can help